# How can i Convert Arabic(Hijri) Date Format into English(US) Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Convert **Hijri**(Arabic) Date into **US**(English) Date Format..

For Ex,Current Hijri Date --> **07-08-1434** (dd-MM-yyyy)

I want to Convert like this--> **16-06-2013** (dd-MM-yyyy)

Answer (score -1):

use this function... it can be help u:
first crate a string array to store all format for u :

```
private string[] allFormats={"yyyy/MM/dd","yyyy/M/d",
            "dd/MM/yyyy","d/M/yyyy",
            "dd/M/yyyy","d/MM/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd",
            "yyyy-M-d","dd-MM-yyyy","d-M-yyyy",
            "dd-M-yyyy","d-MM-yyyy","yyyy MM dd",
            "yyyy M d","dd MM yyyy","d M yyyy",
            "dd M yyyy","d MM yyyy"};
```

then :

```
  private CultureInfo arCul;
            private CultureInfo enCul;
 private HttpContext cur;
```

and finaly use this function:
(string format: use specific format that u want !  AND string hijr: Hijri Date to string )

```
public string HijriToGreg(string hijri,string format)
        {

            if (hijri.Length<=0)
            {

                cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :Date String is Empty");
                return "";
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(hijri,
                   allFormats,arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return tempDate.ToString(format,enCul.DateTimeFormat);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :"+hijri.ToString()+"\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
```

I Hope it can Help...

Comment: How do you initialize `arCul`?

Comment: Also, you should never use a general `catch`, you should only catch the exceptions you expect. And returning an empty string for invalid input is a bad idea too.